# AWS lambda timeout and getRemainingTimeInMillis()

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I used a `context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()` for lambda execution time checking. So, the documentation says

> getRemainingTimeInMillis() – Returns the number of milliseconds left
>   before the execution times out.

When the notification function was developed I saw a remaining time in milliseconds, but now the context.getRemainingTimeInMillis() returns something like 35966320, 35178103 millis.
It looks like this is a timestamp from the begin of the day.

Is there way to change a getRemainingTimeInMillis() representation?

Comment: The function works as expected for me. Are you using provisioned concurrency? (edit: so if the timeout is set to 3s, the function will return something like `299x` at the start of the execution)

Comment: Provide your piece of code